# Forcing derived classes to declare themselves as Spring bean

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

How can I control, that all classes, that derive from a certain class, **have to** be declared as `@Component` (that means as a Spring bean)? Is Spring offering a mechanism for controling this via the parent class?

Answer (score 1):

Workarround: you could use [AspectJ to declare warnings][1] (or errors) if the subclass of your parent class does not have a `@Component` annotation.

*(I am not an AspectJ expert, so I can not write you the needed AJP declaration. But I have done something similar some years ago, so I am pretty sure that this approach works.)*

**rough** sketch, contains maybe some syntax errors:

```
pointcut requiresComponentAnnotation(): yourParentClass+ 
         && !get(@Component)
declare warning : requiresComponentAnnotation() : 
        "expect: @Type(type = \"org.springframework.stereotyp.Component\")";
```

Comment: This might be a good idea for a workaround - thank you - although I was looking for a ready to use mechanism.